# Whats faster: ranged queries on partition keys or individual equality queries on PK's in Azure table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a need to run queries against table storage.  I need to get specific data from about 10 consecutive partition keys.  To be more precise, my Azure table contains a PK/RK pattern so that every PK has about 300 rows.  Within each PK, I need to retrieve about 100 rows.

I can do either 1 call like this:

```
                var query = table.CreateQuery<Item>()
                    .Where(n => string.Compare(n.PartitionKey, fromPk, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0 &&
                                string.Compare(n.PartitionKey, toPk, StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0 &&
                                string.Compare(n.RowKey, fromRk, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0 &&
                                string.Compare(n.RowKey, endRk, StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0
                    ).AsTableQuery();
```

or
10 calls to this:

```
                var query = table.CreateQuery<Item>()
                    .Where(n => string.Compare(n.PartitionKey, pk, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0 &&
                                string.Compare(n.RowKey, fromRk, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0 &&
                                string.Compare(n.RowKey, endRk, StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0
                    ).AsTableQuery();
```

What's better?

Answer (score 0):

I've not profiled it myself, I'm guessing that in some situations the differences could be pretty small, but the single query is probably the way to go.

The single query is reasonably efficient, but because of the amount of data you have (about 3000 rows in the result set) and the fact that you will get at most 1000 rows at a time, this will result in at least 3 calls to the API under the hood.

The individual queries are probably individualy faster  and you probably won't result in getting a continuation token and you could run them in parallel.  If you can't run the queries in parallel I would expect the latency of the requests to overwhelm any query performance difference.

Comment: Your question prompted me to look into continuation tokens again.  ATS will issue continuation tokens when it crosses PK boundary... so I'm guessing that multiple queries, especially in parallel mode are faster https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135718.aspx

Comment: I'd forgotten that little detail, so yes I expect you're right.